# Find file created at a specific time of the day

Tags: bash, unix

i need to use the find command in bash to search for files created on a specific hour of the day,
for example files created between 12:00 and 12:59. is there any way to do that ?
That's the code I'm trying to use:

```
num2=$((num+1))
min1=$((num * 60))
min2=$((num2 * 60))
find . -path '.' -cmin +$min1 -cmin -$min2 -ls
```

where the num variable is specified by the user.
I'm still a beginner and can't figure it out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use this specific `find` command:

```
find . -type f -newermt "2020-06-14 12:00" ! -newermt "2020-06-14 13:00" -ls
```

With variables:

```
start_time=12:00 stop_time=13:00 date=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)
find . -type f -newermt "$date $start_time" ! -newermt "$date $stop_time" -ls
```

`FreeBSD` compatible, even 2011 7.4 version

Relevant part of `man find`:

> -newerXY reference
>     Succeeds if timestamp X of the file being considered is newer than timestamp Y of the file reference.  The letters X  and  Y
>     can be any of the following letters:
>
> **a**   The access time of the file reference
>     **B**   The birth time of the file reference
>     **c**   The inode status change time of reference
>     **m   The modification time of the file reference**
>     **t   reference is interpreted directly as a time**
>
> Some  combinations are invalid; for example, it is invalid for X to be t.  Some combinations are not implemented on all systems; for example B is not supported on all systems.
>   If an invalid or unsupported combination of XY is specified,  a  fatal
>     error results.  Time specifications are interpreted as for the argument to the -d option of GNU date.  If you try to use the birth time of a reference file, and the birth time cannot be determined, a fatal error message results.
>   If  you  specify  a test  which  refers to the birth time of files being examined, this test will fail for any files where the birth time is unknown.

Comment: Wow. I'm on GNU find 4.7.0 and `-newermt` is listed neither in the man page nor in the `--help` - yet it works!

Comment: No, that's because you have to match `-newer` in `man find`. The last 2 chars have to be chosen in a list